# How do find the correct JSON object to pass into the GSON parser?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm building an app to learn how to parse JSON with Kotlin.  At the first stage of my app, I'm trying to extract the images from JSON and paste them in my `ImageView` but unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:774)
            at 
ca.ozbek.popularmovies.MainActivity$fetchJSON$1.onResponse(MainActivity.kt:44)
```

This is the line that its pointing to:

`val movieFeed = gson.fromJson(body, MovieFeed::class.java)`

After debugging the project with a break-point on the above line, I saw that `body = "okhttp3.internal...."`, which means this is what I'm passing into the GSON parser.  I'm trying to retrieve the poster_path from my API:

```
{
  ...
  "poster_path": "/abc.jpg",
  ...
}
```

This is my code for MainActivity where I'm trying to parse the JSON data:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)

        fetchJSON()
    }

    fun fetchJSON(){
        val url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=..."

        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback{

            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                println("Failed to execute")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                val body = response?.body().toString()
                println(body)

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                val movieFeed = gson.fromJson(body, MovieFeed::class.java)

                runOnUiThread { recycler_view.adapter = RecyclerAdapter(movieFeed) }

            }
        })
    }
}

class MovieFeed(val movies: List<Movie>)

class Movie(val original_title: String,
            val poster_id: Int,
            val overview: String,
            val vote_average: Double,
            val release_date: String,
            val reviews: String)
```

Comment: Typically, this problem comes when the server does not send JSON back and sends back something else, such as an error HTML page. Log the response to LogCat and see what it looks like.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Your println() might already be going to LogCat. If not, use android.util.Log.

Comment: @CommonsWare Just did that.  Not getting anything.

Comment: Then you will need to determine why you are not getting a response from the server.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've dissected the problem even more (check the edit) but I don't understand how I'm not passing a GSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Call `string()`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html#string--), not `toString()`, on the `ResponseBody`:

```
val body = response?.body().string()
```

Comment: That seems to be my error.  Thank you very much.  I've accepted your answer.  If you think that my question was well asked, could you give me an upvote?